# Spring Cloud Stream DLQ, Producer and Consumer Residing under Multiple Application

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-cloud-stream

I have producer in say Application A with the below configuration,

## Producer Properties:

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.packageVersionUpdatesPublishChannel.destination=fabric-exchange
    spring.cloud.stream.bindings.packageVersionUpdatesPublishChannel.producer.requiredGroups=version-updates
    spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.packageVersionUpdatesPublishChannel.producer.exchangeType=direct
    spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.packageVersionUpdatesPublishChannel.producer.routingKeyExpression='package-version'
    spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.packageVersionUpdatesPublishChannel.producer.bindingRoutingKey=package-version
```

And I have a Consumer for the same Queue in an another application say B,

```
#Consumer Properties:
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.packageVersionUpdatesConsumerChannel.destination=fabric-exchange
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.packageVersionUpdatesConsumerChannel.group=package-version-updates
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.packageVersionUpdatesConsumerChannel.consumer.max-attempts=1
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.packageVersionUpdatesConsumerChannel.consumer.exchangeType=direct
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.packageVersionUpdatesConsumerChannel.consumer.durableSubscription=true
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.packageVersionUpdatesConsumerChannel.consumer.bindingRoutingKey=package-version
#DLQ
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.packageVersionUpdatesConsumerChannel.consumer.autoBindDlq=true
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.packageVersionUpdatesConsumerChannel.consumer.dlqDeadLetterExchange=
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.packageVersionUpdatesConsumerChannel.consumer.dlq-ttl=30000
#Error Exchange Creation and Bind the Same to Error Queue
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.packageVersionUpdatesErrorPublishChannel.destination=fabric-error-exchange
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.packageVersionUpdatesErrorPublishChannel.producer.requiredGroups=package-version-updates-error
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.packageVersionUpdatesErrorPublishChannel.producer.exchangeType=direct
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.packageVersionUpdatesErrorPublishChannel.producer.routingKeyExpression='packageversionupdateserror'
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.packageVersionUpdatesErrorPublishChannel.producer.bindingRoutingKey=packageversionupdateserror
```

Now say for example if the Application A boots first, then the Queue version-updates would be created without any dead letter queue associated with it.

And now the when the Application B starts, this is the exception I get and the channel gets shudtdown, I think this is because app B is trying to re-create the queue with a different configuration

inequivalent arg 'x-dead-letter-exchange' for queue 'fabric-exchange.version-updates' in vhost '/': received the value 'DLX' of type 'longstr' but current is none

Can anyone please let me know, how do i solve this, where my requirement is to create a Queue in App A and App-A would simple produce the messages onto this queue

And App-B would consume the same and my requirement is to support re-tries after X amount of time through DLQ

Answer (score 1):

`required-groups` is simply a convenience to provision the consumer queue when the producer starts, to avoid losing messages if the producer starts first.

**You must use identical exchange/queue/binding configuration on both sides.**

Comment: thanks @gary for your reply, I will try this again, I tried creating identical properties on both the sides, but if the consumer channel that is declared on producer side via application.properties and via the interface is not in use and if the application which is hosting the producer starts first then also I have seen similar errors...but I will try this again and confirm